# Firebase real time database offline mode is not working properly in Moto e 2gen device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real time database to update the content of my app. It is working perfectly fine when the device in on-line, the content of real time database is fetched to my app properly. In the official documentation its also told that firebase real time database will support off-line mode. And when I tested it in Nexus (Android OS 6.0) , Nexus 5x(Android 7.0) device it was working fine.

But in my Moto e 2gen device(running on Android 5.1) the off-line mode is not working properly. After disconnecting from the Internet the fetched records are showing in my app for few minutes , but after 2 to 5 min the fetched records are vanishing.

Please help me to understand the firebase real time database .Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Try using both `setPersistenceEnabled()` and `keepSynced()` methods

Comment: Thanks a lot @RosárioPereiraFernandes. Your answer is concise and it works.